# Specifying Dockerfile as pipeline job container

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

**Is it possible to specify a Dockerfile as basis for a container job, instead of a reference to an already built container?**

This is possible with Jenkins, and a much appreciated feature:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage("My Stage") {
      agent {
        dockerfile {
          filename 'Dockerfile'
        }
      }
      steps {
        //
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would suggest something like:

```
container: 
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```